# TabBar in .NET MAUI shell app is behind on-screen bottom toolbar

Tags: android, maui, .net-maui.shell, maui-android

I have a MAUI app targeting Android. Im using shell navigation together w/ a TabBar like this:

```
<Shell
    x:Class="MyApp.Mobile.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Mobile"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Mobile.Views"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False" Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor="{StaticResource Secondary}" 
    Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor="{StaticResource Primary}" 
    Shell.TabBarTitleColor="Black" Shell.PresentationMode="Animated"
    Title="MyApp.Mobile">

    <TabBar Route="Landing">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"/>
    </TabBar>
    <TabBar Route="Home">
        <Tab Title="Hem" Icon="house_solid.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DashboardPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Undersökningar" Icon="heart_pulse_solid.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AssessmentStartPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Verktyg" Icon="ruler_solid.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ToolsIndexPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>

</Shell>
```

When I run the app in the emulator the TabBar is placed behind the bottom toolbar. Like this:

[image: Screen dump]

I have tried updating the MainActivity.cs file setting the layout as this:

```
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();

        Window.Attributes.LayoutInDisplayCutoutMode = LayoutInDisplayCutoutMode.Never;
        
    }

}
```

How can I update my app code so that the TabBar doesn't invade the toolbar area?

Cheers,
Peter

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem in the android 13.0 emulator and did you try to test it on the other devices?

Comment: I'll try and deploy to a physical device w/ software buttons and check the result.

Comment: All right, waiting for your feedback.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back until now. I found the cause of this problem. I had set a LayoutInScreen WindowManager flag that shouldn't have been set. So, my bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad! I had erroneously set two WindowManagerFlags: LayoutInScreen + LayoutInsetDecor, which was wrong.